# fswebcam cron: Device or resource busy

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get a picture from webcam on Raspberry Pi every minute. So I wrote a script:

`NOW=$(date +"%H-%M-%S")
fswebcam -r 640x480 /home/pi/$NOW.jpg`

When I run it form command line like `/home/pi/webcam_script`, it works just fine. Then I add a task to cron using `crontab -e`:

```
0-59 * * * * /home/pi/webcam_script >> cronlog 2>&1
```

As a result, no pictures are captured. In `cronlog` file I see the following error message:

```
Error selecting input 0
VIDIOC_S_INPUT: Device or resource busy
```

So, what is wrong and how can I automatically get pictures from a webcam

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_mask=0x3 to /boot/cmdline.txt and restart the device.